# In a Cocoa macOS App, how can I get the degree coordinates of the bottom left corner of a MKMapView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mkmapview

I develop an application for macOS in Objective-C and I have a MKMapView in the main window. When I click a button, I want to calculate the degrees coordinates of the bottom left corner of the visible map, and for the top right corner. I know that MKMapView has a visibleRect property, so my code is:

```
- (IBAction)userDidPressConvertButton:(id)sender {

    MKMapRect mapRect = self.mapView.visibleMapRect;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(mapRect.origin);

    NSLog(@"Latitude %f Longitude: %f", coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude);
    NSLog(@"size width = %f, size height = %f",mapRect.size.width,mapRect.size.height);
}
```

according to the documentation, the property is of type MKMapRect. I have ascertained that its origin member points to the top left corner of the visible Rect. My problem is that while there is the MKCoordinateForMapPoint function that converts to coordinates for the MKMapPoint member origin, the size member's width and height do not have a function to convert to degree coordinates and are not expressed in degrees, but, according to the documentation, in map points. How can I get the degree coordinates of the bottom left corner and of the top right corner of the current visible map ?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to find the visible map rect coordinates from bottom left to top right calling MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect on the map's visible rect. This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)userDidPressFillCoordinates:(id)sender {

    MKMapRect mapRect = self.mapView.visibleMapRect;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(mapRect.origin);

    NSLog(@"Latitude %f Longitude: %f", coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude);
    NSLog(@"size width = %f, size height = %f",mapRect.size.width,mapRect.size.height);

    NSLog(@"%@",MKStringFromMapRect(mapRect));

    MKCoordinateRegion region =   MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRect);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = region.center;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = region.span;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D topRightCoordinates = coordinates;

    coordinates.latitude -= span.latitudeDelta;

    topRightCoordinates.longitude += span.longitudeDelta;


    self.coordinatesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f",coordinates.longitude,coordinates.latitude,topRightCoordinates.longitude,topRightCoordinates.latitude];


}
```